# In the Header.php file, is there a way to swap between one layout and another?

Tags: headers

I want to have one header page for the front page of the site and all other pages that follow by clicking "next" and a different header for all other pages, categories, articles, etc. on the site.  Is there a way to do this within the header.php file or do I have to do something differently?

I'm using a free theme for the backbone of the site and have implemented a child theme to create a unique header as well as add functions separately so that I don't lose changes when the parent theme is updated, so I have minimal space to maneuver in order to affect these changes.

Comment: Ok. Now I realize why the disconnect. I need to clarify that I'm using a primary theme and am, right now, programming a child theme to handle additional functions and create the alternative header. Is there a way to insert the header swap into the index.php without creating a separate one since I'm using a child theme and have only, so far, duplicated the functions.php and header.php pages?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the theme, in most cases you can simply edit `header.php` in your child theme and add a conditional:

```
if(is_home()) {
// code for the header displayed on home & paged
} else {
// code for the header on all other URLs
}
```

`is_home()` will return true if you are on what is referred to as the "blog posts index" - i.e. you're displaying a list of blog posts on the front page - as well as each additional page you reach through the "next" link.

Comment: Where would I put this? There's a lot of code in the header. Would I put it before the doctype tag or down in the body section?

Comment: Wrap it around whatever changes. All pages should have a doctype, so you'd leave that alone, leave meta tags etc. that should be on every page alone, and go down to wherever the code needs to be conditional.

Comment: You can also create template_parts if you want to keep the two interchangeable headers completely separate, then call them conditionally in the `header.php` file. Makes for less code in a single file, which may or may not be useful in your case.

Comment: Ok. I tried to get this one to work and either I was putting the operations in the wrong spot or it just wasn't working. I still had the full header appearing on all pages.

Comment: You might need to use `if(is_front_page())` instead depending on whether you're showing a static Page or the default list of recent posts on the homepage.

Comment: My apologies for the way delayed response. I get busy on other things and forget I'm working on this as a side project. I added a note to my original post above explaining that I'm doing this as a child theme, which may complicate how I can handle it.

Comment: This solution works regardless of whether you're using a child theme or a parent theme, and it works within your "header.php" child theme file which you've already stated exists. Not sure what the disconnect is?

Comment: If I want to leave the default header in place and then call the new header.php file, I wouldn't be able to do it this way? And can the code literally go around everything in the header.php file?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to have multiple header files in a theme, and to have your templates load them based on conditions you choose.

You already have a `header.php` file that gets loaded when a template calls `get_header()`; you can create a new one called `header-front.php` with the markup for your home page and any other pages you choose, and load it instead by calling `get_header( 'front' )`. The parameter that gets passed is the slug of the file (everything in between "header-" and ".php" in the file name.

Comment: Would I put the "front" markup in the index.php file only then?

Comment: You would have all the appropriate header content in `header.php` and `header-front.php`, and call them with `get_header()` and `get_header( 'front' )` in `index.php`. They should be wrapped in conditional checks for `is_home() || is_front_page()` to call the right header for what you need. If true, call header front, else call header.

Comment: My apologies for the way delayed response. I get busy on other things and forget I'm working on this as a side project. I added a note to my original post above explaining that I'm doing this as a child theme, which may complicate how I can handle it.